# Undefined variable: categories (View: in Laravel) How to Solve This

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hy!
i have **problem** in post page of blog using laravel 5.8.
in home page its work fine this same form code for post page but i create error. idk why
i have route for home page

```
Route::get('/' , 'IndexController@index');
```

and this is for post page

```
Route::get('/post/{app}' , [BlogController::Class, 'show']);
```

for the home page and all other pages the indexController is same like 
retrieving the categories i use the @include file for all the pages but when i use the different controller for the post page i create issue.

**Blog Controller**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $post =Post::find($id)->where('status' , 'publish');
        return view('/post')->with('blogs' , $post);
    }
```

**Index Controller**

```
 public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome')
        ->with('post' , Post::all())
        ->with('images' , Image::all()->sortByDesc('publish_at')->take(1))
        ->with('categories' , Category::all())
        ->with('top_index' , Post::all()->where('status' , 'publish')->sortByDesc('publish_at')->take(2)->where('status' , 'publish'))
        ->with('recent_posts', Post::all()->take(8)->sortByDesc('publish_at')->splice(2)->where('status', 'publish'));
    }
```

this work fine but when i use the **Blog controller** in post page where the Index Controller is  also use for Categories the error occur 
Help me Please

**Error**
Undefined variable: categories (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\include\header.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\resources\views\include\header.blade.php)

Comment: Either use `->with('categories' , Category::all())` in your BlogController too or maybe a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers)

Comment: Please edit this question and add view code for clear understand. I think in view you show categories but not send to this variable from controller to view.

Comment: Take a look at [view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass variable in extend function and then use it in child blade as below,

```
@extends('header', ['categories' => $categories])
```

You cannot directly use variable of header in child component blades.
Hope this helps.